# Phaser 3 image is unable to load when I host the website

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting, phaser-framework

so I am working on a game using Phaser framework. Everything is going smoothly until I deploy using firebase. For some reason, when I try to host the game using firebase, I get an error which shows that the image cannot be found[image]

The error that I get is as such: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () ". When I change that asset to another image, it also has the same issue. However, when if I were to open the html file in browser, the asset does load and I can see the image. I am not sure why there is an issue like such, but if you are able to help me out, it would be much appreciated

The code below is how I add the image into the picture

```
preload() {
    this.load.image("engineershirt", "SLICES/upperpri/sm1.png/");
}

create() {
    const engineershirttop = this.add.image(320, 550, "engineershirt");
    engineershirttop.setScale(0.55);
    engineershirttop.setDepth(12);
    engineershirttop.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the slash `/`at the end is too much, it should only be `this.load.image("engineershirt", "SLICES/upperpri/sm1.png");`

Comment: I didnt realized. Such a small mistake but causes so many issues. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @JavierWong No problem, if my answer help please mark it as accepted.